# Increase disk storage for google cloud shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am trying to use Google Cloud Shell as my development platform as it's free and come with an intensive code editor. But at the same time, I struggle because only 5GB disk storage and only 2 projects loaded.
Is there an option to [buy storage for cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/)?

I know i have option to subscribe another VM inside GCP but it doesn't suit me, due to ain't any COOL IDE as i get in Cloud Shell. All i can deal with only vi.

Answer (score 2):

> ***No, You cannot increase the disk size of cloud storage. In fact if you do not use cloud shell for 120 days It will delete your home directory.***
>
> See more limitations [here](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations)

Your second point is an insult to open source community :)

Here is an alternative I can think of:

1. Setup cloud SDK in your local system
2. [Google Cloud Shell Editor](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-google-cloud-shels-new-code-editor) is eclipse's Orion based text editor. You can use eclipse IDE , It will have same shortcut keys and code validation features.
3. Alternatively , You can use [Orion](https://orionhub.org/) in case you're doing web development

I hope this helped.

Comment: OMG! I dont meant to insult the community! I am not a UNIX guru and it took me weeks to configure a working model. So to "vi" my project can kill me easily. I have been working with different IDE but end up the cloud one suit me best. But among all of them, there are integration effort and compatibility bugs... end up i managed to GIT > Code > Test > Deploy > Host perfectly using Cloud Shell! I might consider to move to MS Visual code cloud when i need more space. Thanks for the advises!

Comment: JK :) . Try eclipse once and see if it caters the purpose .

Comment: Thanks pal! have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

there is more disk storage on root folder that you can use it